# Wordpress: changing fields, titles and buttons names

Tags: php, wordpress

I need help with changing some names in wordpress. I already changed a lot of stuff that I need to change, but some questions remain unanswered even after a lot of googling. If you have the time and know what to do, please, help me. I use WP 4.9.1 and standart Twenty Sixteen theme.

1. When you browse any category there is a title that reads **Category: CATEGORY_NAME**. I need it to read only **CATEGORY_NAME**, i.e. get rid of **"Category: "**. *(I tried to look for category.php or similar, but couldn't find any; archives.php doesn't include this string in any visible form)*
2. When you browse posts by author there is a title that reads **Author: AUTHOR_NAME**. I need to change the string **"Author: "**. *(I tried to look for author.php or similar, but couldn't find any; archives.php doesn't include this string in any visible form)*
3. When you browse posts by author there is a title that reads **Tag: AUTHOR_NAME**. I need to change the string **"Tag: "**. *(I tried to look for tag.php or similar, but couldn't find any; archives.php doesn't include this string in any visible form)*
4. When you are viewing the feed there is info about the post near it, that writes date, tags and string **"Comment"** or **"N comments"** if there are any. I need to change this string (both variations to one universal).
5. In the comment section there is information string about the comment **"DATE at TIME / Edit"**. I need to change the word **Edit** and get rid of word **at**.
6. In the post comment section there is a string before the text field that reads **"COMMENT"**. I need to get rid of this string, or change it to blank.
7. In the post comment section there is a button **"POST COMMENT"**. I need to change this text inside the button.

I also looked all over every .php file of the theme in order to find any of these strings to no avail. Thank you a lot for paying attention to this question and all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you found what you were looking for, but I would advise against modifying the theme Twenty Sixteen. The reason is that there might be an update that will replace all of the changes you made. You should instead make a child theme and then make any modifications on that theme which will not be replaced with an update to the parent theme.

Whenever I need to find something and its difficult to find, I use the plugin [Reveal Template](https://wordpress.org/plugins/reveal-template/). It will show you exactly what file is used for each page at the bottom  if you are logged in. Its free and you can delete it after using it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this plugin would definetly help earlier while editing all the other staff, but doesn't help with curent problems. Thank you anyway, I will use it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answers! All the archives titles are rendering in wp-includes/general-template.php get_the_archive_title(). All comments staff.. well, I just decided to disable comments :)